# Cleaning top inside of old Plano tackle box

Tags: fishing-tackle

I have an old Plano plastic tackle box that I am trying to clean up. It has these places on the underside of the lid. I’ve tried a few different things to clean it up to no avail. This box has been stored in attic and in unheated area for 25 plus years. Any guess as to what it is and how to clean it?

[image]

Comment: I had cleaned that area up already before taking pic. I was curious as to what may had caused it and if it could be removed. If I had to leave it, it wouldn’t be a big deal as it doesn’t go all the way through. Just on surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely caused by soft baits eating the plastics. Older plastics weren't made to resist the solvents that make soft baits soft and squishy.

Check out:

https://www.bassmaster.com/tips/charlie-hartley-right-way-store-soft-plastics

http://www.carolinasportsman.com/details.php?id=14260

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wouldn’t have thought of that.  I patched up as best as I could with epoxy. Could you check out my other question in this forum and see if you know answer to it?

Comment: It is this question https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/20198/16217