# What is this yellow powder substance in a bag with yellow hair jigs?

Tags: fishing-tackle, gear-identification

I found a bunch of hair jigs inside an old tackle box that has been stored in attic. Several of them appeared unopened, but there was a yellow powdery substance in bag. Anybody know what substance is and have they seen it before?

[image]

Comment: A couple of thoughts: oxidization of the metallic jig head (if not lead) causing the paint to become friable and break up. Perhaps a pork-rind tail disintegrated? But since there is no other packaging, I suspect it is the remains of a card that was packaged inside the bag with the lure to show the product name and info. Those things break down easily over time - especially if they've ever gotten wet or in really humid conditions.